# How do I resample a pandas Series using values around the hour

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, resampling

I have timeseries data recorded at 10min frequency. I want to average the values at one hour interval. But for that I want to take 3 values before the hour and 2 values after the hour, take the average and assign that value to the exact hour timestamp.

for example, I have the series

```
index = pd.date_range('2000-01-01T00:30:00', periods=63, freq='10min')
series = pd.Series(range(63), index=index)
series
2000-01-01 00:30:00     0
2000-01-01 00:40:00     1
2000-01-01 00:50:00     2
2000-01-01 01:00:00     3
2000-01-01 01:10:00     4
2000-01-01 01:20:00     5
2000-01-01 01:30:00     6
2000-01-01 01:40:00     7
2000-01-01 01:50:00     8
2000-01-01 02:00:00     9
2000-01-01 02:10:00    10
                       ..
2000-01-01 08:50:00    50
2000-01-01 09:00:00    51
2000-01-01 09:10:00    52
2000-01-01 09:20:00    53
2000-01-01 09:30:00    54
2000-01-01 09:40:00    55
2000-01-01 09:50:00    56
2000-01-01 10:00:00    57
2000-01-01 10:10:00    58
2000-01-01 10:20:00    59
2000-01-01 10:30:00    60
2000-01-01 10:40:00    61
2000-01-01 10:50:00    62
Freq: 10T, Length: 63, dtype: int64
```

So, if I do

```
series.resample('1H').mean()
2000-01-01 00:00:00     1.0
2000-01-01 01:00:00     5.5
2000-01-01 02:00:00    11.5
2000-01-01 03:00:00    17.5
2000-01-01 04:00:00    23.5
2000-01-01 05:00:00    29.5
2000-01-01 06:00:00    35.5
2000-01-01 07:00:00    41.5
2000-01-01 08:00:00    47.5
2000-01-01 09:00:00    53.5
2000-01-01 10:00:00    59.5
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```

the first value is the average of 0, 1, 2, and assigned to hour 0, the second the average of the values for 1:00:00 to 1:50:00 assigned to 1:00:00 and so on.

What I would like to have is the first average centered at 1:00:00 calculated using values from 00:30:00 through 01:20:00, the second centered at 02:00:00 calculated from 01:30:00 to 02:20:00 and so on...

What will be the best way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You need `series.resample('60min',base=30,loffset='30min').mean()`. `base` for adjusting resample interval, and `loffset` for adjusting the resulted index. For more details check the doc of pandas.

Comment: Thanks @Ian, you proposed solution worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with:

```py
series.index = series.index - pd.Timedelta(30, unit='m')
series_grouped_mean = series.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60min')).mean()
series_grouped_mean.index = series_grouped_mean.index + pd.Timedelta(60, unit='m')
series_grouped_mean
```

I got:

```
2000-01-01 01:00:00     2.5
2000-01-01 02:00:00     8.5
2000-01-01 03:00:00    14.5
2000-01-01 04:00:00    20.5
2000-01-01 05:00:00    26.5
2000-01-01 06:00:00    32.5
2000-01-01 07:00:00    38.5
2000-01-01 08:00:00    44.5
2000-01-01 09:00:00    50.5
2000-01-01 10:00:00    56.5
2000-01-01 11:00:00    61.0
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I got a `cannot cast unit min` error. however if I change `unit=m` it will work but the result is not the expected: the first average should be 2.5, not 2:

Comment: Thanks @Nico. Moving backwards and forward the index is also a possible solution. It worked!